# Chrome automatically blocks javascript when open Developer (F12)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a problem with Chrome running on my PC.
Websites are running fine on Chrome, but whenever I open developer tools (F12), Chrome blocks that site's javascript. Keep the developer tools opened, and refresh the page (F5), Chrome loads the site with without any scripts.

This happens to all websites.

- Incognito mode doesn't encounter the issue.
- I checked settings in Chrome and it allows JS.
- I tried to disable extensions, doesn't work.
- I re-installed Chrome, doesn't work.
- I tried to run using a different Chrome user account. **Work fine**.

But I am a developer so I don't want to use incognito mode all the time or use different account.

Please help,

Hoang

Edit: 
* Add screenshot
[image: js blocked]

Comment: Show us the screen shot of your "Inspect element window."

Comment: thanks for feedback. I added a screenshot.

Comment: check out the pic I added..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `settings` from "Inspect element window" and **untick** the "*disable Javascript*" check box

[image: Chek the pic below]

Comment: I didn't know when it was checked. Thanks for your help!!